# Creating automatically shortest way network between given point objects via OSM roads (without overlaying line objects) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, point, qgis-processing, network

I am trying to automatically generate a grid between point objects (buildings). The grid should be automatically laid over public roads.  So far I use the QGIS Processing Tool "Shortest way (point to layer)". As a network vector layer (input) I use OSM roads. The points to be connected are the centroids of the buildings.

**Problem:** The network is generated automatically and is almost fine that way, however, it seems like multiple line objects are generated that overlay each other, so further processing with this generated layer (such as length determination) leads to insufficient results. To show the overlapping in a screenshot is unfortunately difficult. You will notice the overlay when you try to delete line objects of the generated grid because there is still a line (or multiple lines) underneath.

**Target:** Continue to automatically create a network between centroids over OSM roads (line objects) by finding the shortest path, but the result should consist of one (or more) line objects that do not overlay.

Is there a feasible solution to my issue? Perhaps there is an existing plugin (I have tried many, e.g. "points2one or Short Path etc.", but none really worked well) or an existing QGIS tool?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Matrix tool in ORS Tools for QGIS sounds like it is what you are looking for.

OpenRouteService:
https://github.com/GIScience/orstools-qgis-plugin/wiki/ORS-Tools-Help

Comment: Thank you David. Unfortunateley the ORS Tool doesnt really work. I tried it via the QGIS integrated tool 'Network Analysis'->'Point to Layer'. This is basically exactly what I am looking for. Unfortunateley this tool creates multiple lines (from each point to the layer). Do you have an idea how to avoid this kind of "double" lining?

Comment: ORS is a third party plugin. It is not related to the network analysis tool.